# How to write the output of re.search into a file, line-by-line

Tags: python-2.7

The below code out is written all in one line:

```
p=open("/var/tmp/input1","r")
q=open("/var/tmp/input2","w")
for line in p:
    m=re.search(r'disk@[a-z](.*)[a-z],',line)
    if m:
       select=m.group(1)
       q.write(select)
```

All I want is the output line by line.

Comment: You're looking for `q.write(select + '\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `q.write(select + '\n')`. This is because `file.write` *does not write* a newline by default.

If you're on python2, you can use this instead:

```
print >> q, select
```

That'll print your data line by line, redirected to the file `q`.